# Primitive Recursion maps

Tags: logic, computability

Is there an example of a bijective map pi: N^2 --> N (where N = natural #'s) which is primitive recursive?

I'm thinking along the lines of projection function but can't quite spell it. Are there some examples?

And how is it bijective as opposed to injective or sujective?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the map $$f \colon \mathbb N^2 \to \mathbb N$$ defined as $f(n,m)=2^n(2m +1) - 1$ this is primitive recursive and it's also bijective.
Bijectivity follows directly by the unique factorization's theorem: indeed for every natural number $x \in \mathbb N$ we have that $x+1 > 0$ can be uniquely factor as the product of finite sequence power of primes $x=2^{n}p_1^{n_1}\dots p_k^{n_k}$ where the $p_i$ are odd primes, the product $p_1^{n_1}\dots p_k^{n_k}$ is odd so it can be expressed as $2m + 1$ for a unique $m \in \mathbb N$. So $x+1 = 2^n(2m+1)$ for a unique pair $(n,m) \in \mathbb N^2$ and so $x= 2^n(2m + 1) - 1$.

For the primitive recursion part, we have that the functions 
$$g \colon \mathbb N \to \mathbb N$$
$$n \mapsto 2^n$$ 
$$h \colon \mathbb N \to \mathbb N$$
$$m \mapsto 2m + 1$$
the multiplication 
$$ \cdot \colon \mathbb N^2 \to \mathbb N$$
and the predecessor 
$$p \colon \mathbb N\setminus \{0\} \to\mathbb N$$
$$p(n) = n-1 $$ 
are primitive recursive, so the function $f=p \circ (\cdot)\circ (g,h)$ which is obtained by composition by these function is primitive recursive too.

Comment: @ArthurFischer thanks for pointing out, I'll edit, thanks. :)

Comment: Details, details, details.. ;-)  (Looks good now, BTW.)

Comment: @ArthurFischer enough details?

Comment: You misunderstood, I think.  Your previous version was fine.   By "Details, details, details.. ;-)" I was referring to the small error regarding the bijectivity of your original function $f$.  I apologise if this was not clear.